# Aggregate in R with parameter list

Tags: r, list, parameter-passing, aggregate

I'm very new to R and running out of ideas how to solve the following problem :(

My dataset 'test' looks like this

```
A  B  C  y     z
a1 b1 c1 0.10  0
a1 b1 c2 0.01  1
a1 b2 c1 0.20  1
a1 b2 c2 0.10  0
a2 b1 c1 0.10  0
a2 b1 c2 0.01  1
a2 b2 c1 0.20  0
a2 b2 c2 0.30  1
```

I want to aggregate my dataset by the some of the 'y' values of the two dimensions 'A' and 'B' which can be done by

```
> aggregate(x = test$y, by = list(test$A, test$B), FUN=sum)
```

and returns the correct result:

```
Group.1 Group.2 x
   a1      b1   1
   a2      b1   1
   a1      b2   1
   a2      b2   1
```

So far, so good. In this simple case I can explicitly write the column names, but what if I want to parameterize them? Somehow like

```
 > fields = 'test$A, test$B'
 > aggregate(x = test$aL, by = list(.(fields)), FUN=sum)
```

it throws an error that the arguments must have the same length. 
So how can I parameterize the aggregate list? I would be very grateful for any tips.

Comment: why not `fields <- list(test$A, test$B)` and then `aggregate(..., by = fields,..)`?

Comment: Another method, `fields <- c("A", "B"); aggregate(test$y, test[fields], FUN=sum)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to make `fields` a list with your variables i.e.

```
fields <- list(test$A, test$B)
aggregate(test$y, by = fields, FUN=sum)
```

or create a function,

```
fun1 <- function(v1, v2){aggregate(test$y, by = list(v1, v2), FUN = sum)}
fun1(test$A, test$B)
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `aggregate` based options in the comments, the syntax for some efficient methods such as `data.table` or `dplyr` are below.

We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(test)`), grouped by 'fields', get the `sum` of 'y'

```
library(data.table)
fields <- c("A", "B")
setDT(test)[, .(y = sum(y)), by = fields]
#    A  B    y
#1: a1 b1 0.11
#2: a1 b2 0.30
#3: a2 b1 0.11
#4: a2 b2 0.50
```

---

Or using `dplyr`, we can pass the objects in `group_by_` with `.dots` argument and get the `sum` of 'y'.

```
library(dplyr)
test %>% 
    group_by_(.dots = fields) %>% 
    summarise(y = sum(y))
#    A     B     y
#  <chr> <chr> <dbl>
#1    a1    b1  0.11
#2    a1    b2  0.30
#3    a2    b1  0.11
#4    a2    b2  0.50
```

Comment: what does the ``.dots`` argument do?

Comment: @CyrusMohammadian  You could read the [dplyr vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html) for NSE or [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/dplyr-use-cases-non-interactive-mode/)